# PaymentsDemo in playn-samples fails with "iss is missing"

Tags: playn

In the PaymentsDemo included with PlayN, I get the following error:

```
iss is missing. Please add its value in the web.xml.
```

The error message comes as a callback response to `failureHandler` from `inappPayments.encodeJWT`. As far as I can tell, no source files or XML files explain what `iss` is, or how to add it to `web.xml`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iss` is the *sellerIdentifier* you get when creating a Google Wallet account. For bootstrapping you can use a sandbox account, or use [Google's sandbox merchant](https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/docs/tutorial) (that page also shows how to create a sandbox customer). Do that by modifying the `servlet` tag in *web.xml* to the following:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>EncodeJWTServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>playn.payments.server.JWTEncodedServiceImp</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>aud</param-name>
        <param-value>Google</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>typ</param-name>
        <param-value>google/payments/inapp/item/v1</param-value>
    </init-param> 
    <init-param>
        <param-name>iss</param-name>
        <param-value>14204953094352168571</param-value>
    </init-param> 
    <init-param>
        <param-name>secret</param-name>
        <param-value>PWGknVgi6zt_BU1qrO1hXg</param-value>
    </init-param> 
</servlet>
```

The `aud` and `typ` parameters should always be like above. Change `iss` and `secret` to match your account details.